# Shifting gears is too hard

Tags: shifter, shifting

I bought my son a new bike (Early Rider Seeker 20) and at the first ride it turned out that he is not able to shift gears down (5 to 4 or 4 to 3 asf) because it is too hard to press. I tried it myself and it is indeed really hard, even for me. It is a Box Four gearshift.

I did some research on the internet and saw that apparently many people have the same problem and exchanged it with a Shimano. I am wondering if I can do anything else to make it more easy to shift.

Are there any other ways to resolve this?

Comment: Is it stiff if you release the pinch bolt at the rear derailleur? You'll need to tug on the inner cable as you shift up, with the RD spring out of the picture.  If you open up the shifter as if to replace the cable,  does the cable move freely in the housing?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is an easy solution. “Trigger“ style shifters simply require quite some force, dexterity and hand/finger size. Many children bikes come with grip/twist shifters for this very reason.

If shifting works properly and the rear derailleur’s spring is able to pull the chain to the smaller sprockets I don’t think you have excessive friction in the cables.

In case it’s not obvious: Since the bike comes with a derailleur shifting system you have to keep pedaling while you shift. But don’t put much pressure on the pedals while you do it. *Don’t* stop pedaling to shift.

Answer (score 1):

I have had different correspondences with the shift developer, the bike developer and the retailer. Their solution were:

> we suggest, is to take the bike to a willing mechanic and ask if they
> would be able to remove the clutch. We ask that a trained bicyle
> mechanic performs this work. The clutch is quite simple and can be removed from the derailleur. once this has been done, the shifting force needed is significantly less.